# Не удается прикрутить проверку названий файлов на наличие русских символов

Tags: python

Есть небольшой инструмент для проверки изображений добавляемых в проект. Пытаюсь приделать к нему проверку названий этих изображений на наличие русских символов, но вне зависимости от того, есть ли они в названии, я ловлю сообщение из errors_log

```
def check_for_invalid_characters(urls, alphabet=set('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ')):
    errors_log = []

    for i in urls:
        if not i.endswith(".png"):
            urls.remove(i)

    array_names = make_names_from_urls(urls)

    for i in array_names:
        if alphabet.isdisjoint(array_names):
            errors_log.append(f"{i} has invalid characters")
    return errors_log
```

Answer (score 0):

Общие символы надо искать не с `array_names`, а с именем файла

```
if not alphabet.isdisjoint(i):
    errors_log.append(f"{i} has invalid characters")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_for_invalid_characters(urls):
    urls[:] = [i for i in urls if i.endswith(".png")]
    errors_log = [i for i in make_names_from_urls(urls) if re.search('[а-яА-ЯёЁ]', i)]
    return errors_log
```